# .Net based web crawler sample

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, web-crawler, search-engine

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I want to find a tool (open source) which crawls all web pages for a web site, and for any other domain pages which is linked by this web site, I want to skip to crawl them (I only need page for this specific domain only). For crawled web page, I want to store them into local file directory.

Any samples or ready to use open source tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arachnode.net](http://arachnode.net/) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Good stuff, is there a web based interface so that we can make query against the full-text analysis results?

Comment: Hi Steve, how good is Arachnode.net for non en-us language? Any experience of index/search for non en-us language, like France, Japanese? Any plug-in needed for such language? (I think keyword extraction, indexing and parsing may be different for different languages?)

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, Steve! I have marked your reply as answered.

Comment: I'm afriad I have not used it (yet), I was just reading about it when I saw yur question:)

Comment: @Steve Haigh: Note on your link its broken, apparently wiki doesn't consider an article on Arachnode.net to be "notable" lol. guess SO doesn't count.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of AN.

AN indexes all languages by default.  Nothing to configure.

- Mike

Comment: There is a web and a service interface to examine your results.

It was really disappointing to have the Wiki page removed for AN.  The page was present for almost a year until someone flagged it.  Even though AN has thousands of users, many of the users do use AN for commercial purposes.  With AN being the base for many businesses our users are somewhat hesitant to expose how they get their data.  Of course, this kind of link is something that Wikipedia looks for to consider something 'notable'.  And, I suspect that the bar for notability is somewhat higher for commercial applications.

Comment: Additionally, personal choice by the moderators of Wikipedia also affects article inclusion, as other crawlers in the Web_Crawler category (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspseek are as 'notable' as AN is.  ::mike